# Почему при вычислении координат left и top мы учитываем координаты границы и её ширину

Tags: javascript

Я пытался решить задачу "Передвиньте мяч по полю", в которой надо было переместить мяч на место клика мышки в поле. В решении использовались координаты, которые вычислялись следующим образом:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
      #field {
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
        position: relative;
        border: 10px solid black;
        background-color: #00ff00;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      #ball {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0; /* по отношению к ближайшему расположенному предку (поле) */
        top: 0;
        transition: 1s all;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body style="height: 2000px">
    Нажмите на поле для перемещения мяча.
    <br />
    Мяч не должен выходить за границы поля.

    <div id="field">
      <img src="https://ru.js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball" /> . . . . . . . .
      . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
    </div>

    <script>
      let block = document.getElementById("field");
      let ball = document.getElementById("ball");
      block.addEventListener("click", func);

      function func() {
        let fieldCoords = this.getBoundingClientRect();

        let left =
          event.clientX -
          fieldCoords.left -
          block.clientLeft -
          ball.offsetWidth / 2;

        let top =
          event.clientY -
          fieldCoords.top -
          block.clientTop -
          ball.offsetHeight / 2;

        const cursorX = event.clientX;
        const cursorY = event.clientY;

        ball.style.left = left + "px";
        ball.style.top = top + "px";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Вопрос: зачем мы в координатах left и top учитываем координаты границы и её ширину. Причем здесь это вообще ?!

Comment: Думаю потому, что _"Мяч не должен выходить за границы поля"_. А также, чтобы курсор был всегда в центре мяча.

Comment: Всегда можно убрать "лишнее" - сразу будет видно что от этого поменялось... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Координаты и размеры родительского контейнера высчитываются для того, чтобы независимо от его расположения на странице, значения для дочернего блока были верными и не выходили за установленные ограничения.

Можно чуть сократить. Итоговый код такой:

```js
let block = document.getElementById('field');
let ball = document.getElementById('ball');
block.addEventListener('click', func);

function func(ev) {
  let fieldCoords = this.getBoundingClientRect();

  let left = ev.clientX - fieldCoords.left - ball.offsetWidth / 2;
  let top = ev.clientY - fieldCoords.top - ball.offsetHeight / 2;

  if (left < 0) left = 0;
  if (top < 0) top = 0;
  if (left > fieldCoords.width - ball.offsetWidth) left = fieldCoords.width - ball.offsetWidth;
  if (top > fieldCoords.height - ball.offsetHeight) top = fieldCoords.height - ball.offsetHeight;

  ball.style.left = left + 'px';
  ball.style.top = top + 'px';
}
```

```css
#field { position: relative; width: 200px; height: 150px; overflow: hidden; background-color: #00ff00; cursor: pointer; }
#ball { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; transition: 1s all; }
```

```html
<body style="height: 2000px">
  Нажмите на поле для перемещения мяча.<br>Мяч не должен выходить за границы поля.
  <div id="field"><img src="https://ru.js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball"></div>
</body>
```